# How can i fix mediaplayer looping space sound in swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode, loops, media-player, swift5

I created mediaplayer with loop. But between loops has space problems. How can I achieve this?

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "rain", withExtension: "wav")
player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
player.numberOfLoops = -1
player.play()
```

Comment: Is there any additional setting you are doing at your end? Or maybe there can be any gap in the wav file itself.

Comment: İt's working great!!!

Answer (score 0):

There can be two alternatives to achieve this -

1. AVPlayerLooper

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlooper

2. AVQueuePlayer.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avqueueplayer